# Why is `27 ** (1.0/3.0)` different from `27 ** (1/3)`?

Tags: ruby

Please let me know if this is correct way to get the cubic root.

I can't understand why

```
27 ** (1.0/3.0) #=> 3
```

is different from

```
27 ** (1/3) #=> 1
```

Comment: @to-all-responders: wow, what a race condition. Please just don't starve the question author:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
1.0 / 3.0 # => 0.3333333333333333
27 ** 0.333 # => 2.9967059728946346

1 / 3 # => 0
27 ** 0 # => 1
```

The second is an example of integer division. How many threes are there in one? Zero. Any number in power 0 is 1.

Answer (score 4):

The first division is a decimal division and the latter is an integer division

that is `1.0/3.0` will yield a decimal result whereas `1/3`will yield an integer result which in this case i `0`

the results will therefor be different since it's the result of either

```
27**0.333...
```

or

```
27**0
```

which of course are clearly different.

It's enough to force one of the operators to be decimal for the entire operation to yield a decimal result e.g. 1/3.0 will yield 0.3333...

Answer (score 4):

Integer division results in integers:

```
irb(main):004:0> 1/3
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> 1.0/3.0
=> 0.3333333333333333
```

`27**0 = 1`. `27**(1/3) = 3`

Answer (score 3):

`(1/3)` returns `0` since `3` is an integer. in ruby, if you divide using integers for both the divisor and dividend, you going to get an integer value. and since anything raised to `0` is `1`, your get `1` as the answer

`(1.0/3.0)` returns `0.3333` since you're not dividing 2 integers so you get `3` from `27 ** 0.33...`

Answer (score 0):

Type conversation.

When you compute 1.0/3.0 - It is decimal

Which is 1.0/3.0 = 0.33 # which is a decimal

1/3 - It rounds to the nearest integer.

Thus:

```
27 ** (1.0/3.0) #=> 3 
is different from
27 ** (1/3) #=> 1
```